# Flow rate of oil vs rapid temperature changes

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, flow

We have a air over oil lubrication system. The air compressor is putting 45 psi of air thru 1/4" id stainless tubing mixed with oil for the lubrication of motor bearings. The system is located outside along some duct work which is up to 300 deg F. We have one issue. Whenever it rains, we get high flow alarms on the system. At normal operation temp., we get 105 CFM. When it begins raining, the line gets cooled rapidly and the CFM goes to 165 which sends an alarm. My theory is the line possibly getting moisture/sweat inside. Water being heavier than oil. Moisture flowing thru the bearing faster than the oil? Anyone care to chime in?

Comment: The high pressure inside the line will prevent water intrusion, but it will NOT prevent heat transfer.  Is it possible to insulate the line to prevent rapid cooling?  Is your flow meter calibrated for 300 deg F?  If so, what effect would the flow meter see if the flow temperature dropped to 200 deg F or 150 deg F?  You may want to consult an instrumentation guy on this problem.